# What is the canonical use for the "sys" and "adm" groups?

Tags: linux, permissions, groups

Since the beginning of time (or as long as I remember anyway) linux systems have had a "sys" and an "adm" group. What is the canonical use for them? Would it be appropriate to use either for a "super user" group? (Group permissions on directories, in sudoers, etc).

Comment: I suspect this one is going to be a tough one to define, w/ some of these groups likely dating back to days of Unix yore. Some Linux distros may actually use these groups. Arch, for example, actually defines their usage: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Users_and_Groups#System_groups

Comment: Might be better question for http://unix.stackexchange.com/ . I asked a similar question about the [operator user](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11638/what-is-the-point-of-the-operator-user)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no *standard* requiring any interoperability meaning of this groups.

Traditionally the `adm` group is used to give a user access to some sort of system log files. 
See e.g. `ls -l /var/log`.

The `sys` group normally intended to give a user some kind of administration rights.
E.g. [*archlinux*](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Users_and_Groups#System_groups) use this group for cups administration. Other distributions behave differently. 
E.g. on *ubuntu* the group `lpadmin` is used for cups administration. 
The `sys` group here is still defined, but seems to be unused.

Comment: Reference for [adm group on Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/SystemGroups#Other_System_Groups):

Answer (score 5):

You can list the groups by this:

```
$cat /etc/group
```

Uses of adm and sys groups:

`adm`: Group adm is used for system monitoring tasks. Members of this group can read many log files in `/var/log`, and can use `xconsole`. Historically, `/var/log` was `/usr/adm` (and later `/var/adm`), thus the name of the group.

`system` :  This group is used for configuration and maintenance for `hardware` and `software`.

Hope this [link](http://wiki.gacq.com/index.php/Debian_default_system_groups_description) will help..

Comment: Reference for [adm group on Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/SystemGroups#Other_System_Groups):